# Class methods access level internal by default

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Usually your class have many methods. Its annoying to set the access modifier for all of them as private and keep one or two with no access modifier.

**Is there a way to let all methods private by default and give the access modifier to the public ones? maybe by assigning an access modifier for the class.**

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no such a thing, you have to "private" -or maybe fileprivate- your methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move all your private methods to an extension in the same file and mark it as `fileprivate`.

```
class Foo {
    // public stuff, stored properties etc.
}

fileprivate extension Foo {
    // private methods, computed properties etc.
    func bar() {
        // this method is fileprivate
    } 
}
```

Comment: it doesnt seems to work on view controllers. compilation error: decleration only valid at file scope

Comment: @hasan83 `extension`s are declared outside of the type they extend. You put it inside of the original declaration.

Comment: oh out of the class. let me try

Comment: @hasan83 You have to use `fileprivate`, not `private`. And put both in the same file, as before.

Comment: It worked. my problem was cause I didnt name the extension as the name of the class :)

Comment: Oh yeah. Named categories is an objc concept. Not present in Swift.

Comment: one more thing. I call one of the function as #selector(CountdownController.setCountdown). it forces me to expose it to objective c by adding @objc  to the function

Comment: And that's a good thing to make explicit (adding `@objc` where you rely on the objc runtime)