# changing a class's default access control

Tags: swift, swift3, access-control

Swift classes have default access control set to `internal` and each time we require to change it we have to explicitly set it.
is there a way we can change default access control?

Moreover, is there a way to encapsulate access controls?

e.g.:

```
 class Object{
 private:
    var foo: Int
    var fu: Int
public:
    init()....
```

just like it is possible in `c++`?

Comment: No, there isn't and that's a good thing. In Swift, internal is always default. From the documentation: "All entities in your code (with a few specific exceptions, as described later in this chapter) have a default access level of internal if you do not specify an explicit access level yourself. As a result, in many cases you do not need to specify an explicit access level in your code."

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692367/class-methods-access-level-internal-by-default.

Comment: @MartinR thank you for the reference but that does not answer the second part of my question.